# How to sort an array containing class objects by a property value of a class instance?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-2.0, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an array of object by a specific field in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301822/how-to-sort-an-array-of-object-by-a-specific-field-in-c)

Given the following code:

```
MyClass myClass;
MyClassArray[] myClassArray = new MyClassArray[10];

for(int i; i < 10; i++;)
{
    myClassArray[i] = new myClass();
    myClassArray[i].Name = GenerateRandomName();
}
```

The end result could for example look like this:

```
myClassArray[0].Name //'John';
myClassArray[1].Name //'Jess';
myClassArray[2].Name //'James';
```

How would you sort the MyClassArray[] array according to the myClass.Name property alphabetically so the array will look like this in the end:

```
myClassArray[0].Name //'James';
myClassArray[1].Name //'Jess';
myClassArray[2].Name //'John';
```

***Edit**: I'm using VS 2005/.NET 2.0.

Comment: Exact dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301822

Comment: It's not the same thing as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: **Well, *by all appearances,* it's the same thing.** If you're gonna contest a duplicate flag, then at least be prepared to explain why your question is different from one previously asked, and why the answers given for that one won't help you in your situation. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: Not enough blood in your nicotine stream, eh Shog? :)

Comment: Something like that. :-)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a duplicate to me, despite the fact the titles are similar, because the other question is actually about Lists, not arrays. The accepted answer is using Linq and List functionality that arrays lack. The accepted answer here is what worked for me, while those answers couldn't.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(VS.80).aspx) overload that takes a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(VS.80).aspx) parameter:

```
Array.Sort(myClassArray,
    delegate(MyClass x, MyClass y) { return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name); });
```

Comment: I needed the same but with descending order, just negated the return result. it worked fine :)

Answer (score 24):

Have MyClass implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) interface and then use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx)

Something like this will work for CompareTo (assuming the Name property has type string)

```
public int CompareTo(MyClass other)
{
    return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
}
```

Or simply using Linq

```
MyClass[] sorted = myClassArray.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToArray();
```