# How to return a query from cosmos db order by date string?

Tags: linq, lambda, azure-cosmosdb, datetime-format

I have a cosmos db collection. I need to query all documents and return them in order of creation date. Creation date is a defined field but for historical reason it is in string format as MM/dd/yyyy. For example: 02/09/2019. If I just order by this string, the result is chaos.

I am using linq lambda to write my query in webapi. I have tried to parse the string and try to convert the string. Both returned "method not supported".

Here is my query:

```
var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyModel>(CollectionLink)
                            .Where(f => f.ModelType == typeof(MyModel).Name.ToLower() && f.Language == getMyModelsRequestModel.Language )
                            .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationDate)
                            .AsDocumentQuery();
```

Appreciate for any advice. Thanks. It will be huge effort to go back and modify the format of the field (which affects many other things). I wish to avoid it if possible.

Comment: I tried to construct a new string to yyyyMMdd format so I can simply compare the string. I got "unsupported ORDER BY clause" error. Exact error as described in https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/11/06/a-few-cosmosdb-query-limitations/.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? If so,you could mark it for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chen Wang.Since the order by does not support derived values or sub query([link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/17762254-native-support-for-sub-query-projections)),so you need to sort the derived values by yourself i think.

You could construct the `MM/dd/yyyy` to `yyyymmdd` by [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#udfs) in cosmos db.

udf:

```
function getValue(datetime){
    return datetime.substring(6,10)+datetime.substring(0,2)+datetime.substring(3,5);
}
```

sql:
    SELECT udf.getValue(c.time) as time from c

[image]

Then you could sort the array by property value of class in c# code.Please follow this case:[How to sort an array containing class objects by a property value of a class instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304278/how-to-sort-an-array-containing-class-objects-by-a-property-value-of-a-class-ins)

Comment: Thank you Jay. I ended up re-formatting the string just as you described. No other way around in my knowledge.