# sort an array of a class in C#

Tags: c#

In my program, I have a class like this:

```
Class Customer{

    double Start;
    double Finish;
    double Wait;
}
```

and I created an array of this class:

```
Customer[] customer = new Customer[300];
```

How I can sort this array according to Start values Descending or Ascending?

Thanks...

Comment: You may want to specify if LINQ is an option or not.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx) method to sort the array in-place:

```
Array.Sort(customer, (x, y) => x.Start.CompareTo(y.Start));
```

or in descending order

```
Array.Sort(customer, (x, y) => y.Start.CompareTo(x.Start));
```

Answer (score 8):

If would prefer to use a `List` of `Customer`, however you can apply the same function on the *array*:

```
List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer>;
var orderedCustomerList = customerList.OrderBy(item => item.Start);
```

---

Refer to:

[Enumerable.OrderBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx)

[Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx)

Comment: `OrderBy` is available on anything implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, including a normal array. Still, +1 from me

Answer (score 4):

In ascending order by `Start`:

```
var sortedCustomers = customer.OrderBy(c => c.Start);
```

And descending order by `Start`:

```
var sortedCustomers = customer.OrderByDescending(c => c.Start);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use icomparer and you need to write your custom code after implementing icomparer in your class

Answer (score 1):

you need to implement IComparable for your Customer class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[C# Tutorial - Sorting Algorithms](http://www.publicjoe.f9.co.uk/csharp/sort00.html)

[Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

You can also use LINQ [Dynamic Sort With LINQ](http://www.thereforesystems.com/dynamic-sort-with-linq/)

[How to sort an array of object by a specific field in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301822/how-to-sort-an-array-of-object-by-a-specific-field-in-c)