# How Array.Sort sort a class that contains strings and doubles?

Tags: c#

In some code I'm looking through the writer goes:

```
Individual[] candidates = new Individual[tournSize];
for (int i = 0; i < tournSize; ++i)
candidates[i] = population[indexes[i]];
Array.Sort(candidates);
```

Which property would it sort it by if the class contains: string s; and double d.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of object by a specific field in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301822/how-to-sort-an-array-of-object-by-a-specific-field-in-c)

Comment: OP's asking specifically what goes on under the hood, not how to sort the array.

Comment: For me, `Array.Sort` just throws `InvalidOperationException`, if array have two or more different not null references.

Answer (score 0):

Specified in the documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx, each element must support `IComparable`, in which case the result is sorted by those definitions, and if an element doesn't support that interface then the result is undefined.

Comment: public class Individual
    {
        public string chromosome;
        public double fitness;
    }
the classs doesnt inherit from icomparable. yet the code works

Comment: @BinkyNichols yes, the spec says the result is undefined however, meaning you can't depend on it, or the result could change from .net 3.0 to 4.0 to 5.0 to 6.0, or from .net to mono.  You'd have to look at the .net runtime code to get any guarantees, and ensure that your project never ever ever upgrades .net or even installs a service pack; the spec guarantees nothing.