# How to pass previous parameter value in Left boundary for other correlation parameter in Load runner

Tags: correlation, loadrunner

I've developed script in Load runner [ WEB HTTP/HTML ].

One of correlation parameter is left boundary of next correlation parameters

Can somebody help to provide the way to use previous correlation parameter value in next correlation parameter value's left boundary?

```
web_reg_save_param("documentHash", lr_eval_string("LB={token}"), "RB=')","Ordinal=1", LAST);
```

Comment: Please add the sample code to your question to understand better.

Comment: Thanks NaveenKumar, but I got the way to declare the correlation parameter in next correlation parameter...

Comment: 'web_reg_save_param("documentHash", lr_eval_string("LB={token}"), "RB=')","Ordinal=1", LAST); ' I used this code in my script

Comment: Use this code `web_reg_save_param("documentHash", 
 "LB={token}", 
 "RB=')",
 "Ordinal=1",
 LAST);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of object by a specific field in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301822/how-to-sort-an-array-of-object-by-a-specific-field-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use your parameter in the left boundary like this:

```
web_reg_save_param("documentHash", lr_eval_string("LB={token}"), "RB=')", LAST);
```

Comment: From both ways , I am able to pick value from response <code> web_reg_save_param("documentHash", lr_eval_string("LB={token}"), "RB=')","Ordinal=1", LAST); OR web_reg_save_param("documentHash", "LB={token}", "RB=')", LAST);

Comment: Is the `lr_eval_string` really necessary? Does this code work for you?

Comment: yes It worked, but I used web_reg_save_param("documentHash", "LB={token}", "RB=')", LAST); Thanks for your answer

Comment: I updated my answer, please accept it as correct for the integrity of stack overflow.

Comment: @Perftester I already answered in the comments. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

As I have already posted the code in the comments. I am the posting detailed answer with an example.

### Example Website

In this example, we will take https://www.example.com to demonstrate the `web_reg_save_param_ex();`.

Here is the output of www.example.com. We will retrieve the marked text using the `web_reg_save_param_ex();`.

[image: Example.com]

### Code

```
//Retrieving the first value.
//c_FirstValue will retrieve the string 'established'


web_reg_save_param_ex(
    "ParamName=c_FirstValue",
    "LB=This domain is",
    "RB=to be used",
    "Ordinal=1",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    LAST);

web_custom_request("web_custom_request",
    "URL=https://www.example.com",
    "Method=GET",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "Resource=0",
    "Referer=",
    "Body=",
    LAST);

lr_output_message("%s",lr_eval_string("{c_FirstValue}"));

//In this function, we are passing the c_FirstValue as a left boundary and retrieves the string 'to'

web_reg_save_param_ex(
    "ParamName=c_SecondValue",
    "LB={c_FirstValue}",
    "RB=be used",
    "Ordinal=1",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    LAST);

web_custom_request("web_custom_request",
    "URL=https://www.example.com",
    "Method=GET",
    "TargetFrame=",
    "Resource=0",
    "Referer=",
    "Body=",
    LAST);

lr_output_message("%s",lr_eval_string("{c_SecondValue}"));
```

### Output Log

```
Starting iteration 1.
Maximum number of concurrent connections per server: 6      [MsgId: MMSG-26989]
Starting action Action.
Action.c(7): web_reg_save_param_ex started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(7): Registering web_reg_save_param_ex was successful   [MsgId: MMSG-26390]
Action.c(15): web_custom_request("web_custom_request") started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(15): web_custom_request("web_custom_request") was successful, 606 body bytes, 328 header bytes     [MsgId: MMSG-26386]
Action.c(24):  established 
Action.c(28): web_reg_save_param_ex started     [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(28): Registering web_reg_save_param_ex was successful      [MsgId: MMSG-26390]
Action.c(36): web_custom_request("web_custom_request") started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(36): Retrieving data from cache for "https://www.example.com"      [MsgId: MMSG-26558]
Action.c(36): web_custom_request("web_custom_request") was successful, 0 body bytes, 0 header bytes     [MsgId: MMSG-26386]
Action.c(45): to 
Ending action Action.
Ending iteration 1.
```